# .NET draw line with outline using GDI+

Tags: .net, graphics, line, gdi+, outline

I'm using .NET for a desktop application.

I'm drawing some lines with cap start and end to use them as arrows, using Graphics.DrawLine with an apropiate pen for it, with some width (lets say 8px).

Now what i want to achive is to add an "outline" to this lines in other color, with 1 or 2 pixels width.

I don't find options to do this using GDI+ (if there is an option for this, perhaps it is in "gdiplus.dll" and i could import it with dllimport).

My first attempt was to draw first the same line with a wider pen, but the effect doesn't fit to the arrow ends as you can imagine.

Any ideas with this?

**UPDATE:** *This is the image with my first attempt drawing two lines, one over the other:*

[image: Outlined line performed with two LineDraw operations with different pen widths]

Comment: "My first attempt was to draw first the same line with a wider pen". This was my first thought, too. Why don't you get the desired result that way? Could you add a screenshot of that 'false' output?

Comment: I have added the image to the question. You can see the blue arrow doesn't "surround" the red one, and the outline doesn't affect the other end of the line, only the large borders. Perhaps this could be hacked making the blue line longer and so, but i would like to avoid this kind of geometry hacks.

Comment: Looks like you could just displace the blue arrow a few pixels along its direction.

Comment: Continuing where Dan Byström left off: consider the blue line as a vector from the first point in the lower left. Take that vector, and lengthen it by the amount you wish to use to "surround". Ideally you are using a vector based library already, so you can create a new vector in the same direction, but a bit longer. The line then starts at the same point, and the end point is the start point plus the lengthened vector.

Comment: Thanks, Dan and Frank, but this is the kind of solution i'm trying to avoid, specially triky when trying to outline the arrow cap end. I'm using only the Windows GDI+ fiunctions provided by .NET.

Comment: @tomasofen You cannot avoid vector arithmetic (using an appropriate library) when writing any vector graphics code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after much experimenting I finally got it

use a GraphicsPath and the widen command,
the one other trick is widen also widens the line to the point it sticks out past the End cap arrow, so use WidthScale on the end cap as well, then just reduce the size of the end cap

```
Using bigArrow As New Drawing2D.AdjustableArrowCap(3, 3)
   bigArrow.WidthScale = 1.5
   
   Using objPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 10)
      objPen.CustomEndCap = bigArrow

      Using objPath As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
         objPath.AddLine(50, 50, 100, 100)
         Using objWidenPen As New Pen(Color.Empty, 10)
            objWidenPen.CustomEndCap = bigArrow
            objPath.Widen(objWidenPen)
         End Using

         gr.DrawPath(objPen, objPath)

      End Using
   End Using

   Using objPen As New Pen(Color.CornflowerBlue, 10)
      objPen.CustomEndCap = bigArrow
      gr.DrawLine(objPen, 50, 50, 100, 100)
   End Using
End Using
```

the result looks much better

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A little late for this answer but I have one that works better, not perfect but better

draw the arrow 4 times with different off sets then draw the main one over it like this

```
Using bigArrow As New Drawing2D.AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5)
   ' Shadow
   Using objPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 5)
      objPen.CustomEndCap = bigArrow
      gr.DrawLine(objPen, 50 - 2, 50 - 2, 100 - 2, 100 - 2)
      gr.DrawLine(objPen, 50 + 2, 50 - 2, 100 + 2, 100 - 2)
      gr.DrawLine(objPen, 50 + 2, 50 + 2, 100 + 2, 100 + 2)
      gr.DrawLine(objPen, 50 - 2, 50 + 2, 100 - 2, 100 + 2)
   End Using
   
   ' Line
   Using objPen As New Pen(Color.CornflowerBlue, 5)
      objPen.CustomEndCap = bigArrow
      gr.DrawLine(objPen, 50, 50, 100, 100)
   End using
End Using
```

it misses the corners but isn't too bad

[image]